# How to find the current capacity of std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

`std::unordered_map` and `std::vector` both have the `reserve` method, which increases the capacity of the collection so that it would be possible to add multiple elements to the collection without enlarging the internal buffer. However, `std::vector` also has a method `capacity()` that returns the current capacity of the collection. `std::unordered_map` does not have such a method. Is there any way to obtain the capacity of `std::unordered_map` using whatever the class already provides?

Comment: Note that any of the given answers does not _guarantee_ the internal buffer won't change size.

Comment: Note that `reserve(n)` on `unordered_map` does not reserve space for n elements but for the number of buckets needed to store n elements given the maximum load factor. `capacity` in the `vector` sense doesn't really apply to `unordered_map`, since a bucket can expand whenever you add an element.

Comment: @rubenvb Do you mean that even `reserve` "does not guarantee the internal buffer won't change size"?

Comment: @rubenvb Also, why do you say that `m.max_load_factor() * m.bucket_count()` does not provide the guarantee?

Comment: @Koosha The collection of buckets will not expand, but the bucket that an element gets inserted in will. (There is no "the" internal buffer.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Good catch! So suppose I start with `std::unordered_map<int,int> m{}`, then I do `m.reserve(10)`, and finally I do `m[1]=1;m[2]=2;...;m[10]=10`. Even if the first two steps do not throw, it is still possible for the last step to throw. Right?

Comment: How would you define a _capacity of an unordered map_?

Comment: @Koosha Why would any of them throw anything? An `unordered_map` is like a `map` without an order.

Comment: @molbdnilo Insufficient memory. Don't get distracted by a small number such as 10. If it helps suppose it is 10 million or billion. I am trying to find an initialization that guarantees there will be no buffer size change, so no memory allocation during the thrid step, and since my keys and values do not throw in constructors/destructor/assignments/hash/equality, I can safety add 10 elements without worring about an exception.

Comment: @Koosha **Every** insertion into an unordered map **does allocate**. Even if the array of bucket is not reallocated, a node needs to be allocated for the inserted element. If you want to avoid this allocation, you might provide your own allocator, for example some memory-pool based with a preallocated buffer. Note that within this allocator, you would need to distinguish between array and node allocations.

Answer (score 2):

A map contains a number of buckets (see [`bucket_count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket_count)) and each bucket can contain a certain number of elements (see [`max_load_factor()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/max_load_factor)). So the total capactity of a `std::unordered_map<X, Y> m;` is

```
m.max_load_factor() * m.bucket_count();
```

Comment: What does even mean to talk about the _capacity_ of an unordered map? This gives the number of elements you can store inside without reallocation of the bucket array, but only if each element will target a different bucket, which is hardly achievable in practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_type std::unordered_map::bucket_count()
```

`std::unordered_map::reserve(size_type n)` requests a capacity change.
Sets the number of buckets in the container (`bucket_count`) to the most appropriate to contain at least `n` elements.

Answer (score 0):

The docs of std::unordered_map::reserve state

> void reserve ( size_type n );
>
> Request a capacity change
>
> Sets the number of buckets in the container (bucket_count) to the most appropriate to contain at least n elements.
>
> If n is greater than the current bucket_count multiplied by the max_load_factor, the container's bucket_count is increased and a rehash is forced.
>
> If n is lower than that, the function may have no effect.

So the equivalent to std::vector::capacity, where reserve changes the capacity when `new_cap` is greater than `capacity()` would be:

```
std::unordered_map::bucket_count() * std::unordered_map::max_load_factor
```